# HTML reserve space for scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a div that may overflow as content is added or removed.

However the UI designer does not want a visible, but inactive scrollbar (as with `overflow: scroll`), and they don't want the content layout to change when one is added and remove (as with `overflow: auto`).

Is there a means to get this behavior, and considering the different scrollbars on different platforms and browsers.

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/qy9a2r00/1/

Comment: There are plugins to replace the native scrollbar, means using javascript.

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ will help, examples here: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do this is to make the width of the items in the container fixed. And you'll have to be conservative with the width of the scrollbar.

```
   .container { 
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       overflow: auto;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       border: 1px solid black;
   }
   .item {
       width: 200px;
...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fr1jnmn6/1/

Answer (score 18):

No browser support this property yet (2021), but [scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter) is a suggested solution for this.

**Update: 2022 - all modern browsers except Safari support the property.**

Comment: Now supported in Chrome/Edge/Opera. Firefox bug waiting for implementors: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1715112

Comment: yes, please check this answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966304/2601507

Answer (score 4):

`overflow-y:overlay` would be a partial solution to this as in, it solves the problem of not wanting the content layout to change when a scrollbar is added or removed. Extra padding or margin can be added so that scrollbar doesn't obfuscate the div behind

Here's the jsfiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/kitwradr/2qcsj6hw/

Comment: It's a non-standard value though

Comment: Bad solution the question is clear that needs to be reserved a place for whether from right, left, bottom or top side.

Comment: Yes, it does work on any side.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup `overflow: scroll` to reserve space for scrollbar and add a class that makes scrollbar hidden

```
body {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Hide the scrollbar by adding class to div (or to body) that will make your scrollbar transparent

```
.scroll-hidden::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.scroll-hidden::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

To check if you have content overflow you can use this lines:

```
  const { body } = document
  const overflow = body.scrollHeight > body.clientHeight
```

If there are no overflow issue we will hide scrollbar and with reserve space

```
body.classList.add('scroll-hidden')
```

If content overflow we will show scrollbar

```
body.classList.remove('scroll-hidden')
```

Try the solution here https://jsfiddle.net/ycharniauski/y0pwftmq/

It's a bit hacky solution. Hope in future css will have some property to reserve space

Answer (score 1):

One cannot know how thick the scrollbar is, using only HTML & CSS and thus do not know the `width` of the (blue) placeholder.

You might solve such a task using scripting. Force a scrollbar in a hidden container and measure the inner and outer width. The difference being the scrollbar-width. Set this width (e.g. as CSS) to the placeholder element. And in the tricky part hide this element whenever a scrollbar is shown.

The usual solution to this problem is the one you do not want.

Comment: Usual solution being, living with "auto" or "scroll" style, replace the entire scrollbar from scratch, or using JS to measure a scrollbar and detect it being added and remove, such that I can adjust the blue bar styles?

Comment: "One cannot know how thick the scrollbar is": What about calc(100vw - 100%)?

Comment: @StrandedKitty Good idea. Sadly this also won't work on many modern OS, since scrollbars often only visible, when the user actually scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parent **div** with a fixed width (the final total width) and a child **div** with a width 16px smaller.
Then the scrollbar will have 16px free in the parent **div**.

The width should always be a number (can't be relative value). In the child **div**, you need to use a number as well. You can't do calc(100%-16px).

```
<div className="user-list">
  <div className="user-list__content">
    {content}
  </div>    
</div>

.user-list {
  width: 500px;  /* total width */
  height: 1000x;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.user-list__content {
  width: 484px;  /* must be 16px smaller */
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but in case anyone comes looking.

Detect the scrollbar and show/hide your blue section based on the scrollbar being visible.  If scrollbar is visible, HIDE your blue sections (apply a style).  If not visible, show your blue padding section.

When the scrollbar becomes visible your padding hides, so the red and green sections will not change size or position.

This article below discusses detecting the scrollbar.  You will want to set up a div somewhere to detect the current scrollbar width ahead of time in order to set your blue boxes to the same width.

[How can I check if a scrollbar is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe `append` a div at the bottom will soft your problem ?

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/k7w574mw/1/

Comment: This answer seems unrelated to the problem. The jsfiddle link is broken